# Image with caption - "figure" box does not adapt to image size, changes image size, long captions do not wrap,

Tags: css, figure, caption, figcaption

Trying to get image captions to act correctly inside contenteditable. Problems I am noticing:

1. The first "Google" image is the original size at 50% - fine.
2. The second "Google" image is inside a "figure" tag.  Problem - The "figure" box extends beyond the width of the image.  I would like it to be the same size as the image - to auto size to the image.
3. The third "Google" image is also inside a figure tag, with float:left.  Problems:  The image size changes.  Also, when you type a longer caption, the box just gets wider and wider - would like the figure box to keep the same width as the image and the longer caption to word wrap in the same width instead of widening, and image size to stay unchanged.
4. Trying "inline-block" in the CSS didn't seem to help matters.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hderr/7L3uad54/1/).

```
<html>
    <head>     
        <style>
            figure {
                //display: inline-block;
                border: 1px dotted gray;
            }
            figure img {
                //vertical-align: top;
            }
            figure figcaption {
                border: 1px dotted blue;
                text-align: center;
            }    
        </style>    
    </head>
    <body style="max-width:700px;">
        <div class="content-area" style="border:1px solid">
            <div contenteditable="">
              <p style="text-align: center;">Welcome to my <b>WYSIWYG</b> Editor</p>   
              <img src="http://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo3w.png" style="width: 50%;border: 5px solid;">
                <figure>
                     <img src="http://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo3w.png" style="width: 50%;border: 5px solid;">
                     <figcaption>Caption 1</figcaption>
                </figure>     
              <br>
                <figure style="float:left">
                     <img src="http://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo3w.png" style="width: 50%;border: 5px solid;">
                     <figcaption>Caption 1 Caption 1 Caption 1 Caption 1 Caption 1</figcaption>
                </figure>  
                <p>Queso camembert de normandie danish fontina. Port-salut parmesan cheese strings cheese and biscuits danish 
                    fontina roquefort port-salut danish fontina. Lancashire rubber cheese ricotta camembert de normandie squirty 
                    cheese goat say cheese emmental. Stilton stinking bishop everyone loves manchego who moved my cheese manchego 
                    boursin queso. Babybel mascarpone cheeseburger cut the cheese.
                    Goat danish fontina pepper jack. Squirty cheese gouda parmesan goat say cheese melted cheese cheesecake 
                    who moved my cheese. When the cheese comes out everybody's happy babybel croque monsieur jarlsberg chalk 
                    and cheese cow the big cheese paneer. Rubber cheese cheesy feet bavarian bergkase say cheese cheese and
                    biscuits babybel monterey jack feta. Squirty cheese squirty cheese mozzarella fondue.
                </p>
                
            </div>
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: to size the figure to the image 's width (or longest word) , try width:min-content. Also, try to keep style and html side by side so you can easily reset a CSS layout without fighting against inline style ;)  example : https://jsfiddle.net/62mcojgy/

Comment: Thank you G-Cyrillus!  Didn't know about min-content!  However, with your fiddle, it is difficult to type text outside of the figure boxes.  Placing the cursor to the right of image 2 or image 3 seems to insert the text into the figure boxes, rather than outside, which is what one would expect...  need more playing around... Ideally would like these figure objects to act like text objects that you could type outside of, float them left or right, and for the captions, to place the cursor in the caption area... it's getting closer though...

Comment: some margin in between elements could help, also white space in the code itself  to start with ? https://jsfiddle.net/83e1zdo7/ once editing starts, edition will add some more elements (p/br).

Comment: here is forked to show/hide plain HTML of your editable div  https://jsfiddle.net/0wdtshg8/1/ so you can see what code is generated while you edit .

Comment: @Cyrillus - if you wish to post your solution in the answer area, I'll will give you a tick!